# c# SQLDATAadapter issue with GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to attach the results of an SQL query to a gridview without creating a collection and instead using the SQLdataAdapter.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                StringBuilder ct = new StringBuilder();

                ct.AppendLine("SELECT DISTINCT........");
                ct.AppendLine("FROM ...... er");
                ct.AppendLine("INNER JOIN ....... ev ON er.eKey = ev.eKey");
                ct.AppendLine("WHERE UserId ='" + _CurrentUser.UserId + "' AND [Type] = 'R' AND EndDate is NULL");
                ct.AppendLine("Order By er.eKey DESC");
                Debug.WriteLine(ct.ToString());
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cm.CommandText = ct.ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ct.ToString());
                SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
                dr.Fill(dt);
            }
```

Previously I was using a simple table format to represent my data and it worked fine.

```
        //    int i = 0;
        //    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        //    {
        //        if (i++ == 0)
        //            Response.Write("<span class='style5'><strong><span class='style6'><center>Existing Enrollments:</center><br/><br/></span></strong></span><table><tr><th>Enroll Key<br/></th><th>Name<br/><br/></th><th>DBA<br/><br/></th><th>Address<br/><br/></th><th>City<br/><br/></th><th>State<br/><br/></th><th>Zip<br/><br/></th><th>TIN<br/><br/></th><th>UserID<br/><br/></th></tr>");
        //        Response.Write("<tr>");
        //        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        //        {
        //            Response.Write("<td>" + row[column].ToString() + "</td>");
        //        }
```

Now I am trying this method:-

```
gvwERAenrollments.DataSource = dt;;
```

and it gives me an empty gridview.

my reference:-
http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/datagridview-sqlserver.htm

Can anyone help me with this? There are going to be multiple rows returned by the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assign the datatable to the gridview directly:
gvwEnrollments.DataSource = dt;

Since this is not a DataSet that you are returning from the sql query, directly assigning the results table to the gridview should work just fine.

Comment: I realized that I changed that quickly, however my gridview shows up with no records... however previously I was using a simple table and that worked.

Comment: I would suspect the sql query is not returning any rows, then.  Put your dt in a Watch, a breakpoint on the DataSource assignment, and inspect the dt for rows.  Then you'll know if your dt is actually getting values from the database.

Comment: huh, its quite strange that with my initial table method I get all the values populated as expected, but with the dt i am getting an {} set.

Comment: I think you'll be fine with the direct assignment, once you get your data into that table :).  Maybe try writing the sql query without using the data adapter?

Comment: whats confusing is that with the same sqldataadapter i get all the values populated into my table...did u take a look at my table code? its in my question .. i updated it to show how i was populating the table.

Comment: You need to take a look at your built string query there, it has some errors in it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47366/discussion-between-brinky-and-philo)

Comment: thanks for your help in chat. Looks like the only thing missing from my code was the DataBind()

Comment: Not a problem, sometimes just talking it through with someone will bring the focus to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you defined dt as a DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

perhaps it should be a DataSet ?

Or .. just use `gvwEnrollments.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: yes i tried both DataSet and the direct assignment. but my gridview shows up as empty. I updated my question.

Comment: If you have SSMS, use the output of Debug.WriteLine(ct.ToString()); and paste into SSMS - see if you get results, remove the where clause - check if any results, re-add where clause bit by bit until you find the part that is excluding all results.

Answer (score 0):

Tables is not a property of DataTable, but it is a property of DataSet.  Also the DataSource may need to be updated, unless you set the control's datasource before actually fetching the data.

You could try:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
gvwEnrollments.DataSource=ds;
```